# How can I disable the bluemix-debug tools for a nodejs application instance in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am in the process of completing the 
[Cloud Application Developer Certification](http://Cloud%20Application%20Developer%20Certification%20-%20Debugging%20Applications)
developerWorks Course.

In Module 3 (Implementing cloud-ready applications) and section 3.3 (Debugging in Bluemix), I set the application instance in development mode by adding this environment variable to the manifest.yml file:

```
ENABLE_BLUEMIX_DEV_MODE: "true"
```

What options are available to revert this change for this application instance?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by Development mode and Normal mode? I not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: im doing a workshop (Debugging applications in IBM Bluemix). This is a step included. Im new with bluemix, trying to learn it. And In Eclipse, at Servers View, when i enable application debug (on my app under the ibm bluemix server) : i have this error : bluemixMgmgClient - ???? [pool-1-thread-1] .... ERROR --- ClientProxyImpl: Cannot create the websocket connections for sia-Lab-autoscale etc. it's a long msg.

Comment: I understand, can you provide the link to the workshop tutorial? Or additional information as I am not familiar with the terminology they are using in the workshop.

Comment: you have to create an account in https://developer.ibm.com/dwcourses/. After that, you select this course : cloud Application Developer Certification Preparation. Finally go to Module 3 (Implementing cloud-ready applications) and section 3.3 (Debugging in Bluemix). It's an interesting course.

Comment: How are you getting into development mode ... Eclipse, cf CLI, or setting environment variables?

Comment: Thank you for the link! I understand your question now. I'll edit the question and provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed the course and I agree it is an interesting course. To remove the development mode from the application you should perform the following steps.

1. Open the manifest.yml file and remove the following completely from the file:

`env:
   ENABLE_BLUEMIX_DEV_MODE: “true”`

2. Clear any cached state of the application that might prevent the application management tools from being removed by removing the application by using the cf CLI:

`$ cf login –a <api endpoint for your Bluemix region>`

`$ cf delete <application_name>`

3. Repush the application:

`$ cf push`